# Laravel 5 и Homestead. Использование алиасов или как вызвать artisan

Tags: php, laravel, homestead

Доброго времени суток.
Установил, настроил и запустил homestead. Vagrant поднимается, сайты работают.
Как мне запустить php artisan команды? Как запустить php phpinfo(); ? Как достучаться к вот этим алиасам в Homestead/aliases

```
alias ..="cd .."
alias ...="cd ../.."

alias h='cd ~'
alias c='clear'
alias art=artisan
// и т.д.
```

P.S К рабочей директории можно обращаться так (настроил в .bashrc):

```
homestead up
//взамен
cd ~/Projects/Homestead
vagrant up
```

Пытаюсь обращаться к алиасам:

```
homestead artisan
homestead php artisan
```

не получается. Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение. Нужно было запустить `vagrant ssh` и перейти в директорию code/проект (/home/vagrant/code/project/). Работает как composer, так и artisan.